# UIButton Selection Event in iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am working on an iPad application, I have three buttons in it Button1, Button2 and Button3. Button1 and Button2 is to load data two different labels and based on these two buttons selection when we click the third button(Button3), the label value respective to the selected button either(Button 1 or Button2) is to be loaded is to be displayed.

```
-(IBAction)btnCustomer
{
    SelectedButton.text = @"Customer";
}

-(IBAction)btnBranch
{
    SelectedButton.text = @"Branch";
}

-(IBAction)btnDisplay
{
    if(btnCustomer.selected == TRUE)
    {
        TitleLabel.text = @"btnCustomert is Selected";
    }
    else if(btnBranch.selected == TRUE)
    {
        TitleLabel.text = @"btnBranch is Selected";
    }
}
```

How can I do this? Any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: I couldn't figure out your question, and please for the next questions try to format your code better.

Comment: Yes. Explain the question clearly.

Answer (score 2):

i think this will help you . . .

```
-(IBAction)btnCustomer
{
    SelectedButton.text = @"Customer";

    btnCustomer.selected = ! ButttonCustomer.selected;

}
-(IBAction)btnBranch
{
    SelectedButton.text = @"Branch";

    btnBranch.selected = ! btnBranch.selected;
}

-(IBAction)btnDisplay
{
    if(btnCustomer.selected)
    {
        TitleLabel.text = @"btnCustomert is Selected";
        btnCustomer.selected = ! ButttonCustomer.selected;

    }
    else if(btnBranch.selected)
    {
        TitleLabel.text = @"btnBranch is Selected";
        btnBranch.selected = ! btnBranch.selected;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `selected` property that you are checking to determine if button is selected or not, needs to be set/reset by your code.

From [Apple docs: `UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW15)(`UIButton` superclass)

> Specify YES if the control is selected; otherwise NO

Also, the `IBAction` method signature is incorrect. It needs to have an argument `sender`(i.e. the button instance which is sending this action message.)

Here is the modified code.

```
-(IBAction)btnCustomer:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*) sender;
    SelectedButton.text = @"Customer";
    //Toggle selected state
    btn.selected = !btn.selected;
}

-(IBAction)btnBranch:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*) sender;
    SelectedButton.text = @"Branch";
    //Toggle selected state
    btn.selected = !btn.selected;
}

-(IBAction)btnDisplay:(id)sender
{
    if(btnCustomer.selected == TRUE)
    {
        TitleLabel.text = @"btnCustomert is Selected";
    }
    else if(btnBranch.selected == TRUE)
    {
        TitleLabel.text = @"btnBranch is Selected";
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!